# How to configure isc dhcp on ubuntu for providing leases for remote networks

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp

I am configuring the `isc dhcp` server on a `ubuntu 16.04` PC. The DHCP server will need to provide
DHCP leases to clients that are on a different network. This is because, the clients will reach the DHCP server over a **VPN connection with combination of IP relay**.

When I configured the DHCP server and ran it I get the error:

`- Not configured to listen on any interfaces!`

The answer in the below thread mentions that the isc dhcp flags this type of config an error and does not start it. Is it possible to make this work?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415888/cant-start-isc-dhcp-server-because-of-the-error-not-configured-to-listen-on-a

Details on my setup

Partial output of ifconfig on dhcp server:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:00:6a:95:9c:2e  
          inet addr:192.168.168.200  Bcast:192.168.168.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**:

```
INTERFACES="enp0s25"
INTERFACESv4="enp0s25"
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**:

```
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.2.102 192.168.2.254;
 option domain-name-servers ubuntuserver.ostechnix.lan;
 option domain-name "ostechnix.lan";
 option routers 192.168.2.101;
 option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the error, such as "`No subnet declaration for eth1`" and "`Not configured to listen on any interfaces!`".

Then I add the `eth1`(the same as `enp0s25`) `subnet` declaration in the `dhcpd.conf` although the subnet not lease the address. And it work.

Try add this config:

```
subnet 192.168.168.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 192.168.168.1;
}
```

Reference from: *[Ubuntu - dhcp server 'not configured to listen on any interfaces'](https://serverfault.com/questions/75702/ubuntu-dhcp-server-not-configured-to-listen-on-any-interfaces/916402#916402)*